# Convert Json response object to string using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

This is the JSON response getting from webservice URL .
 JSON:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "outputQty":"2",
         "orderSummaries":[],
         "categoryName":"test",
         "itemId":1,
         "recipes":[],
         "name":"Laddu"
      },
      {
         "outputQty":"2",
         "orderSummaries":[],
         "categoryName":"Badam Pista Mundiri",
         "itemId":2,
         "recipes":[],
         "name":"Barpi"
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried to get JSON values in html page .So that I tried as like below:

```
$.ajax({  
       type: "GET",  
       url: "http://tomcatworkbench.com/Catering2/secured/getAllItems",  
       dataType: "json",  
       success: function(response) {
         $.each(response, function(idx, obj) {
  console.log(obj);
});
    }
       });
```

or

```
 $.getJSON("http://tomcatworkbench.com/Catering2/secured/getAllItems", function(data){
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        console.log(value);
    });
});
```

Both way returns object only I can't get string values.Please anyone help me to get out this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `JSON.stringify(response)`

Comment: @ricky I got output with all values.But how can I get value from each row and each datatype.Do u have any sample code

Comment: @KavyaShree, please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get `data.data` object.

```
$.getJSON("http://tomcatworkbench.com/Catering2/secured/getAllItems", function(data){
    $.each(data.data, function (index, value) {
       console.log(value);
    });
});
```

```js
var data={
   "data":[
      {
         "outputQty":"2",
         "orderSummaries":[],
         "categoryName":"test",
         "itemId":1,
         "recipes":[],
         "name":"Laddu"
      },
      {
         "outputQty":"2",
         "orderSummaries":[],
         "categoryName":"Badam Pista Mundiri",
         "itemId":2,
         "recipes":[],
         "name":"Barpi"
      }
   ]
}
$.each(data.data, function (index, value) {
    var tr='<tr>';
    tr+='<td>'+value.outputQty+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+value.categoryName+'</td>'+
      '<td>'+value.itemId+'</td>'+
      '<td>'+value.name+'</td>'+
      '</tr>';
    $('table').append(tr);
});
```

```css
td{
   border:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>OutputQuantity</td>
       <td>CategoryName</td>
       <td>ItemID</td>
       <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Object {outputQty: "2", orderSummaries: Array[0], categoryName: "test", itemId: 1, recipes: Array[0]…}.. Im getting like this. How can I get each value from each row

Comment: You can access elements like this: `value.outputQty, value.categoryName`.

Comment: Okie If I use  value.categoryName it will return list of categoryNames in json response.If I want to take first from the list.How could I retrieve.

Comment: `value.categoryName[0]` first object in array is zero indexed.

Comment: Ya I tried already its return first letters of all categoryname

Comment: Your categoryName is a string value not an array. For clarification "list" is usually synonymous with array. `value.categoryName.split(" ")` will split a string into an array by its spaces. `value.categoryName.split(" ")[0]` would be the first value split into your array.

Comment: For instance, `orderSummaries":[]` is an array.

Comment: value.categoryName.split(" ")[0] this returns all categoryName with first word instead taking first value alone.

Comment: If you just want the first objects categoryName just use `data.data[0].categoryName`

Comment: console.log(data.data[0].categoryName); I tried witht his its working

Comment: One more thing I jst want to print list in table with foreach loop.like header with categoryname,outputqty,itemname,th with each row value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135028/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-alexandru-ionut-mihai).

Comment: I tired to find the solution that why response data not accessed individually, i tried many thing but because of not check result.result[0].text . Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

just enumerate response.data

```
$.ajax({  
       type: "GET",  
       url: "http://tomcatworkbench.com/Catering2/secured/getAllItems",  
       dataType: "json",  
       success: function(response) {
           response.data.forEach(function(item) {
               console.log(item.categoryName);
           });

           var firstItem = response.data[0];                                                 
           console.log(firstItem.categoryName);

           var allCategoryNames = response.data.map(function(item) {
               return item.categoryName;
           });
           console.log(allCategoryNames);

           var allCategoryFirstNames = response.data.map(function(item) {
               return item.categoryName.split(' ')[0];
           });
           console.log(allCategoryFirstNames);
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following example.

```js
var response = {"data":[{"outputQty":"2","orderSummaries":[],"categoryName":"test","itemId":1,"recipes":[],"name":"Laddu"},{"outputQty":"2","orderSummaries":[],"categoryName":"Badam Pista Mundiri","itemId":2,"recipes":[],"name":"Barpi"}]};

var data = response.data;
$.each(data,function(i,v){
for(var key in v){
  if(key==="categoryName"){
  console.log(i+". "+key+": "+v[key]);
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```